# How do I infer an element from an object by index?

Tags: reactjs

How do I infer an element from an object by index?

I have an object that has multiple objects in it, I need to output them one at a time, but how do I output an object at a specific index?

```
[obj, setObj] = useState({
 step: {
  title: 'bla bla...'
 },
 step1: {
  title: 'bla bla...'
 },
 step2: {
  title: 'bla bla...'
 },
})

const onHandleWokVariantRender = () => {
    return Object.keys(obj).map((content, index) => {
      const contentControl = control[content];
      return (
        <input 
         placeholer={control.title}
        />
      )
   });
 }; // There will be 3 inputs, step, step1, step2
```

How to display not all three inputs, but for example input with index 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mapping them all at once, use `Object.values(obj)[step]` where `step` is the step you want to display/render.

```js
const obj = {
 step: {
  title: 'bla...'
 },
 step1: {
  title: 'bla bla...'
 },
 step2: {
  title: 'bla bla bla...'
 },
};

const objArray = Object.values(obj);

console.log(objArray[1].title);
```

Alternatively you can track what the active step is and conditionally render the active step via index, i.e. if step 1 is the active step

```
const onHandleWokVariantRender = () =>
  Object.values(obj).map((content, index) =>
    index === step ? <input placeholder={content.title} /> : null
  );
```

Comment: What is index === step? Where to get step from?

Comment: @luckydev Sorry, I thought you were trying to render a single specific step, i.e. like step 0, or 1, or 2, and would have *some* "state" holding this "active step" reference. How does the component know what step it should display?